# Many to many relation table and Linq query to join them

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the given scenario tables having Many to many relation between Departments and Rooms. There is also a junction.
[image]

I have following class named DepartmentWithRoom

```
public class DepartmentWithRoom
{
  public Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }

  public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

  public List<Rooms> RoomList { get; set; }
}
```

Problem: I want to create a list of DepartmentWithRoom object having List of associated RoomId in it using Linq.

I tried but not able to create the join. Please help Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your entities? As code please and not as picture :)

Comment: Post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi Mats391 It is updated

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EF, it should hide the junction table and add two collection navigation properties between `Deparments` and `Roons` entities so, your query could be this way:

```
var result= context.Departments
                   .Where(d=>d.Rooms.Any())// I guess you need only those departments that have rooms
                   .Select(d=>new DepartmentWithRoom{
                                  DepartmentId= d.Id,
                                  DepartmentName=d.Name,
                                  RoomIdList=d.Rooms.Select(r=>r.Id).ToList()
                              });
```

### Update

If the junction table is mapped as part of the model them you should have a collection navigation property in `Department` entity referencing to it, so, your query would be pretty much the same than before:

```
var result= context.Departments
                   .Where(d=>d.Rooms.Any())// I guess you need only those departments that have rooms
                   .Select(d=>new DepartmentWithRoom{
                                  DepartmentId= d.Id,
                                  DepartmentName=d.Name,
                                  RoomIdList=d.DeparmentRoomJunction.Select(r=>r.RoomId).ToList()
                              });
```

Comment: No it is not hiding it. may be it is not a junction but the DepartmentWithRoom has Ids for Room and departments.

Comment: Please, show your entities to give an accurate answer

Comment: @octavioccl: it's possible that OP uses an explicitly stated junction table because they track additional information. E.g. which department has priority access to which room => needs to be stored in the junction.

Comment: @Flater, Got it, yes that could be a possibility, but according with her data schema it doesn't have additional columns, only the ids, that why I assumed EF was going to avoid the junction table

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
  var linqJoin = from j in junctions
                   join d in departments on j.DepartmentId equals d.Id
                   group new { j, d } by new { j.DepartmentId, d.Name } into g
                   select new DepartmentWithRoom
                   {
                       DepartmentId = g.Key.DepartmentId,
                       DepartmentName = g.Key.Name,
                       RoomIdList = g.Select(x => x.j.RoomId).ToList()
                   };
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should solve the problem:-

```
 var result = from department in Departments
                     join junction in Junctions on department.DepartmentId equals junction.DepartmentId into rooms
                     select
                         new DepartmentWithRoom
                             {
                                 DepartmentId = department.DepartmentId,
                                 DepartmentName = department.DepartmentName,
                                 RoomIdList = rooms.Select(r => r.RoomId).ToList()
                             };
```